# What is not supported by DMA (data migration assistant) for onprem to onprem SQL server migration?

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

I am using DMA with the intention to assess and migrate everything from an onprem sql server 2016 into an onprem sql server 2019.

It looks like DMA only allows migration of:

1. User databases, users and permissions (example: grants, revokes, denys)
2. Server logins, roles, custom roles and permissions

It does not migrate:

1. Ssis db and packages
2. Maintenance plans
3. Triggers
4. Linked server configs
5. Server level configs
6. Db level configs
7. System dbs
8. Agent jobs

**What else am I missing in the list?**

Comment: Have you looked at dbatools.io?

Comment: Question is to specifically ask what elements does the DMA tool from Microsoft not support.

Answer (score 1):

I would say everything else that is not inside a user database: certificates, endpoint, AG configurations, server audit and so on.
It's difficult to do a list. Every feature at server level is not cloned.

Comment: The system object permissions are not cloned

Comment: permissions of systems object that are inside a database are clonded. system objects permissions outsed it no.

Comment: What is an example of system object permission outside?

Comment: permission on dmv coming from master datbase as
sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes

Comment: I can't find anything from Microsoft to migrate such things in a clean way

Comment: Why you have to do it? What is not working? do you have an idea of what you have in place or you are trying to do a blind "copy all"? Maybe it is time to evaluate this details at the edge of the configuration. You can eventually set those extra permission after migration if and when someone ask for it. Test your app in the new environment before close the migration and manage all the rest as told before only if and when somene asks for it

Comment: It's a blind task as I don't have any information about the source sql server. I do have access to it. My concern is user's granular permissions to system objects that may break things that we don't know - for example not sure what needs testing